# How do you press a key and make it hold?

Tags: vbscript

To clarify, I don't want to send a keystroke, I would like to send a key hold (like holding down the 'D' key for 10 seconds).

I've tried something like this:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For i = 1 to 1
    WshShell.SendKeys("D")
Next
```

But it doesn't simulate a key hold very well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, you have written an infinite loop: remove `i = i - 1`.  Secondly, if you need to hold `D` key for some time interval, then you must _count_ elapsed time instead of number of tapping a key… Pay your attention to `DateDiff` function and  to `Do...Loop` Statement.

Comment: @JosefZ Sorry if I was unclear, but the example code was just showing a concept I know to do a somewhat key hold, not the real thing. Also, the `D` for 10 seconds idea was just an example to help explain the question. Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: What exactly do you want. Programs can test for keydown and wait for keyup - vbscript can't help. Most programs accept windows processing which is set by BIOS/Windows keyboard settings. A character is sent 15 to 30 times a second with a half second delay after the first. Therefore `{x 300}` would send x for 10 secs or 300 times.